# Firefox keyword search using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, search, keyword, multiparameter

I want to use a **travel planner** making full use of [Firefox' Keyword Searches](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-search-from-address-bar?redirectslug=Smart+keywords&redirectlocale=en-US).

The keyword search basically just inputs a string somewhere in a predefined URL, e.g. `google.com/search?q=%s` with `cats and dogs` will go to `https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=cats%20and%20dogs`.

Q1: However, the URL needs the (current) date, so this needs to be entered variably as well.

Because we need a *starting location* and *final location* we need to enter **two** search string, which is possible (explained [here](https://lifehacker.com/firefox-tip-how-to-set-up-multi-parameter-keyword-sear-240552)).

Q2: I would also like to be able to e.g. enter 'h' for my home address.

The URL format of the travel planner is as follows:

`https://www.ns.nl/reisplanner/#/?vertrek=STARTLOCATION%20Centraal&vertrektype=treinstation&aankomst=ENDLOCATION&aankomsttype=treinstation&type=vertrek&tijd=2023-03-03T15:59&firstMileModality=PUBLIC_TRANSPORT&lastMileModality=PUBLIC_TRANSPORT&disabledTransportModalities=`

I currently have:

```
javascript:var%C2%A0s='%s'; 
url='https://www.ns.nl/reisplanner/#/?vertrek=%s&vertrektype=treinstation&aankomst=%s&aankomsttype=treinstation&type=vertrek&tijd=currentDateInRightFormat&firstMileModality=PUBLIC_TRANSPORT&lastMileModality=PUBLIC_TRANSPORT&disabledTransportModalities='; 
const h='My Home Street 1 My Home Town'
const w='My Work Street 1 Work City'
const currentDateInRightFormat = new Date(new Date().toString().split('GMT')[0]+' UTC').toISOString().split('.')[0].slice(0,16));
t=''; 
qc=0; 
chunks=url.split('%s'); 

for(i=0; i<s.length; i++){
    if(s.charAt(i)=='%22')qc=qc^1; 
    t+=((s.charAt(i)==' '&&qc)?'^':s.charAt(i)); 
}
args=t.split(/\s/); 

nurl=''; 

for(i=0; i<chunks.length; i++){
    nurl+=chunks[i]; 
    if(args[i]!=undefined)%C2%A0{
        args[i]=args[i].replace(/\^/g,' '); 
        nurl+=args[i]; 
    }
}
location.replace(nurl,'< BR>');
```

So I would like to be able to:

- enter the currentDateInRightFormat in the URL
- use the string 'h' which then inputs my predefined home address, string 'w' for work, etc.

Comment: Having looked at the Mozilla piece about Keyword Searches that you linked to and what I took from that was that you invoke the context menu (r-click) when on a site rather than something that you would do in the browser address bar as it seems your question is talking about - though it is a little confusing. It used to be possible (still is in Chrome ) to create special bookmark shortcuts ( previously known as `bookmarklets` ) which would seem a likely candidate for what I think you are trying to do

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I am going to stick with this though, it's almost finished and I like Firefox, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: It is not clear how you actually intend to use the above

Comment: I just reread your comment and now I understand. You *do* actually use the address bar, the r-click is just for the setup. It's really great, it simplifies looking for cat videos on YouTube to, if you took 'y' as the keyword: `y catvideos`. Now I want to use multiple strings to search for, like `travelplan startloc endloc`. It's really worth setting up, takes a few minutes and you save 2 seconds every search :)

Comment: OK - I understand the right click is used only when creating the new bookmark / keyword. What is not clear is where you intend to add the above Javascript. I just setup one of these and the only field in the edit options that looks likely is the URL

Comment: Yes, you indeed put this script with leading "javascript:" in the URL field. It's explained in more detail [here](https://lifehacker.com/firefox-tip-how-to-set-up-multi-parameter-keyword-sear-240552)

Comment: so that is basically a bookmarklet as I mentioned just that it is tied to the site via the `keyword`... If I understand correctly though what you want to do is read from the address bar - so, if the keyword was "Foo" and you entered, in the address bar, "Foo Bar" - you would hope to read "Bar" and use that within your scriptlet?

Comment: Yes, exactly! For YouTube e.g.: "y cat videos"

Answer (score 1):

Given that I do not believe you are able to read the address bar content using Javascript the closest I came to doing what I think you are trying (?) to do was as follows:

```
javascript:let home='Forfar';let work='Dundee';
let args={
    'aankomstvertrektype':'treinstation',
    'aankomsttype':'treinstation',
    'type':'vertrek',
    'tijd':(new Date(new Date().toString().split('GMT')).toISOString().substring(0,16)),
    'firstMileModality':'PUBLIC_TRANSPORT',
    'lastMileModality':'PUBLIC_TRANSPORT',
    'disabledTransportModalities':''
};
args.vertrek=prompt('Enter start location.\nUse "h" for "Home"',home);
args.aankomst=prompt('End End location.\nUse "w" for work.',work);
if(args.vertrek=='h')args.vertrek=home;
if(args.aankomst=='w')args.aankomst=work;
const endpoint='https://www.ns.nl/reisplanner/#/';
let url=new URL(endpoint);
url.search=new URLSearchParams(args).toString();
location.href=url;
```

When added to the Firefox bookmarklet doodah thingy it is then invoked by typing the `keyword` in the address bar and then supplying content when prompted - `h` and `w` can be used and will be substituted for the defined values of `home` and `work`. The default values are already set as `home` and `work` for start/end

Not speaking dutch or knowing locations to use I am not 100% sure that this is functioning as hoped

Comment: Thanks! This does seem to work partly. It prompts for the start and end point, but sadly it doesn't actually take those args. I will try to make it work, also with the '%s', and post here if I manage. Thanks again for your elaborate answer! :)